# How to use MethodValidationPostProcessor when having multiple (custom) validators?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

In one of my Spring applications, I am planning to use `MethodValidationPostProcessor` for validating service method parameters. As I know, for this, I'll have to have a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` object in the ApplicationContext, which in turn will have to have one `validator` injected. I am doing it like this in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor getMethodValidationPostProcessor(){
    MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    processor.setValidator(validator());
    return processor;
}
```

And then, my service classes look like this:

```
@Service
@Validated
public class SomeService {

    public void someMethod(@Valid SomeForm someForm) {
        .
        .
        .
    }

}
```

But, a few of my objects would be needing some custom validators. For example, for the signup form, I plan to use a *JoinDataValidator* extending the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, like this:

```
@Service("joinDataValidator")
public class JoinDataValidator extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors) {
      super.validate(target, errors);
      // check for duplicate email
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
      return JoinForm.class.equals(clazz);
    }

}
```

So, I'll be needing multiple validators, for different service classes. I could not figure out how to tell the configured `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to use different validators depending on the Service class being validated, or what could be a good way to handle this kind of scenario. I would appreciate help.

**Update**: Have created a ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12563

Comment: Initially, I had posted the question short hoping that that would be a right way for someone to quickly understand the issue. Basically the issue is "how to use @MethodValidationPostProcessor when having multiple (custom) validators?" As the question went on hold, I have now elaborated it. I think it's a very genuine issue to be posted at stackoverflow, and would request to reopen it.